# How to call second recurring job minute after first one?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have two recurring jobs.

First one calls MethodOne() every 20 seconds

Second one calls MethodTwo() every 20 seconds.

I want second one to start 1 minute after first method so they never start simultaneously.

currently, this is my code. It doesn't work because both jobs start at the same time.

```
     RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<MethodCaller>(a => a.MethodOne(), "*/20 * * * * *"); 
     Thread.Sleep(60000);
     RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<MethodCaller>(a => a.MethodTwo(), "*/20 * * * * *");
```

Both MethodOne() and MethodTwo() are void. They both have one line of code.

```
     Debug.Writeline("Method Called");
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(60000);` Ouch!

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular [System.Threading.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.8) you can specify the due time and period separately. So you could have the same period, but different delays. Not familiar with Hangfire, so I cannot suggest how to use that to do the same thing.

Another option would be to let the first job trigger the second job.